# Gaze at it/out at it/out over it?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

If you're standing next to a field gazing at it, do you gaze at it/out at it/out over it?

What's most natural?

Comment: Or *gaze [out] **across** the field*. According to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gazed+*+the+field&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cgazed%20%2A%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgazed%20over%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgazed%20across%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgazed%20at%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgazed%20upon%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0) the most common prepositions between ***he gazed*** and ***the field*** are ***across, over, at, upon*** (most common first). But obviously they all occur, so they're all "natural".

Comment: gaze out over it implies you are in a house or structure: you gaze out [of a window or opening]+ over it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @FumbleFingers' comment, i.e. **across, over, at, upon** would be the most common.

Another thing I'll say is that to use the word "out", i.e. "gaze out across the field", to me suggests that one is "within" something else. This would most commonly be used if, for example, someone were inside of a house, looking out of a window, across a field.

Comment: The point is that one can gaze out across or over a field. The upon is rather archaic in most contexts.

Answer (score 0):

He stood outside, **gazing at** the field.
He stood outside, **gazing across** the field.
He stood outside, gazing over the field.
He stood at the **window**, **gazing out at** the field.
He stood at the **window**, **gazing out across** the field.
He stood at the **window**, **gazing out over** it.

gazing **out** [of a/the window] = **generally** implies there is a window. Although, one can also conceivably say: He stood at the edge of the field, gazing out over it.
There, the gazing out implies from the edge of it.

If you are outside, you don't usually "gaze out".
I have put the more usual combinations above. There may be others.

I would stay away from "upon" here.